# Sitecore XP 10.3 Upgrade - CD Instance Time-Out Issues

Tags: upgrade

We are currently in the process of upgrading our Sitecore XP version from 9.0.2 to 10.3, and unfortunately, we are encountering challenges, specifically related to time-out issues on our CD (Content Delivery) instance.

The CM (Content Management) server is performing as expected; however, the CD instance is experiencing frequent 500 time-out errors, causing disruptions to our operations.

To provide you with more context, here are the key details of our environment:

**Sitecore Version**: XP 10.3

**Hosting**: Azure PaaS

**Web Database**: Hyper-scale, Gen5, 8 vCores

**CD App**: Premium v3 P3V3

**Database Size**: 55GB

Upon analyzing the logs, we have identified two suspects:

```
Request Time-Out: Error executing SQL command`**SELECT
  [ItemId],[Order],[Version],[Language],[Name],[Value],[FieldId],[MasterID],[ParentID],[Created]
FROM
( SELECT
[Id] AS [ItemId],0 AS [Order],0 AS [Version],'' AS [Language],[Name],'' AS [Value],[TemplateID] AS [FieldId],
[MasterID],[ParentID],[Created] FROM [Items]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
[ParentId] AS [ItemId],1 AS [Order],0 AS [Version],'' AS [Language],NULL AS [Name],
'',NULL,NULL,[Id],NULL  FROM [Items]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
[ItemId],2 AS [Order],0 AS [Version],'' AS [Language],NULL AS [Name],[Value],
[FieldId],NULL,NULL,NULL  FROM [SharedFields]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
[ItemId],2 AS [Order],0 AS [Version],[Language],NULL AS [Name],[Value],[FieldId],
NULL,NULL,NULL FROM [UnversionedFields]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
[ItemId],2 AS [Order],[Version],[Language],NULL AS [Name],
[Value],[FieldId],NULL,
NULL,NULL FROM [VersionedFields]) AS temp
  WHERE [ItemId] IN (SELECT [ID] FROM [Items] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE [ID] = @itemId)
  ORDER BY [ItemId], [Order] ASC, [Language] DESC, [Version] DESC**`

ManagedPoolThread:Continuous appearance of a log related to **Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher.**
```

To add More detail , Here is the DTU Graph

[image]
Your prompt response would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use SXA?

Comment: No, we are not using SXA.

Comment: increase the cache size in the application, and increase the database upto 150 GB

Comment: Hi Avish. This question is likely to require a lot of discussion and will probably be unique to your implementation. I would take this to slack or the community forums.

Comment: Can you check all the configs inside App_Config and see if any of the index on CD server has indexing strategy different than `manual`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak : Earlier is was onPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance but we changed it to manual. But the problem persist.

Comment: You may want to try to remove entries from `web` database `EventQueue` table